# Rails 4 - select_tag does not pass id for field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, select

I cannot pass the lecture_id to the created object: 
Basically it should create the project with the lecture_id based on the dropdown menu. It does not seem to pass the data.

If for instance I add <%= f.input :lecture_id %> it will pass the data

```
  <%= simple_form_for(@project) do |f| %>
   <%= f.error_notification %>

    <div class="form-inputs">
      <%= f.input :title %>
      <%= select_tag(:lecture_id, options_for_select(@lecture_options)) %>
      <%= f.input :company_name %>
      <%= f.input :phone_number %>
      <%= f.input :body %>
   </div>

   <div class="form-actions">
     <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
   def new
     @lecture_options = Lecture.all.map{|u| [u.title, u.id]}
     @project = Project.new
     respond_to do |format|
        format.html
        format.js
    end
    authorize @project
   end 

 def create 
     @project = current_user.projects.build(project_params)
    if @project.save 
        flash[:success] = "You have successfully created a project."
        redirect_to profile_path(current_user)
     else 
        render action: 'new'
     end
   authorize @project 
 end


   def project_params
       params.require(:project).permit(:company_name, :phone_number, :body, :user_id, :title, :lecture_id)
    end
```

Models:

```
 Lecture.rb 
    has_many :projects  

Project.rb
 class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
     belongs_to :lecture
  end
```

Comment: Can you place your entire `form_for` code?

Comment: I just did it. If for instance I add <%= f.input :lecture_id %> it will pass the data

Comment: just make `<%= f.select(:lecture_id, options_for_select(@lecture_options)) %>`

Comment: Works! thanks mate for your help

Answer (score 0):

You should change select_tag to :

```
<%= select_tag("project[lecture_id]", options_for_select(@lecture_options)) %>
```